# Is there a way to get thousands separator in a Value to string geometry node? (so it is easier to read)

Tags: node-editor

[image]

Hello

I can't seem to find a solution to this issue.
I have tried to enter a geometry node that get the value going from 0 to 3M$ but there is no option to enter thousands separator to make it easier to read.
Is there a way to do this in a simple way?

Thanks